# Как правильно сделать такой эффект в пагинации?

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Как сделать [**такую**](http://www.annamorosini.it/en/) анимацию пагинации перемещения точек элементов между числами  01, 02 , 03 , 04 ?

```css
.paination {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <span>01</span>
  <span>02</span>
  <span>03</span>
  <span>04</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Там используется не `SVG`, даже не `Canvas`=) (`HTML`+`CSS`)

Comment: @Arthur я думаю без js не обошлось =)

Comment: Мне кажется там достаточно создать немалое количество `div`, добавить каждому `transition-delay`, а при клике трансформировать

Comment: @Arthur     transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 38.4219, 0); вот примерно что то такое используется не когда не видел такое свойство trasition-а матрикс .Да и кстати вы правы там div-ы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как было сказано в комментариях, подобный эффект можно сделать на `HTML`+`CSS`.
(*эффект работает при `hover`'e*). Пример на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/St1myL/pen/deJoaM) с использованием цикла для генерации `transform-delay` in `SCSS`.
**Update:** *Исправлена анимация.*

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
var px = document.getElementsByClassName("px");
btn.onclick = function() {
  Array.from(px).forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.add("offset");
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#toggle {
  background: crimson;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.70rem 0.75rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#toggle:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.line {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.offset {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}

.px {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.px:nth-child(1) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.px:nth-child(2) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(3) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.px:nth-child(4) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(5) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.58s;
}

.px:nth-child(6) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.56s;
}

.px:nth-child(7) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.58s;
}

.px:nth-child(8) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(9) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.px:nth-child(10) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.45s;
}

.px:nth-child(11) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(12) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(13) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.43s;
}

.px:nth-child(14) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.44s;
}

.px:nth-child(15) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.59s;
}

.px:nth-child(16) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.54s;
}

.px:nth-child(17) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.56s;
}

.px:nth-child(18) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.52s;
}

.px:nth-child(19) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.px:nth-child(20) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.56s;
}

.px:nth-child(21) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(22) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.px:nth-child(23) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.52s;
}

.px:nth-child(24) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.48s;
}

.px:nth-child(25) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.46s;
}

.px:nth-child(26) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.45s;
}

.px:nth-child(27) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.52s;
}

.px:nth-child(28) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.54s;
}

.px:nth-child(29) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.55s;
}

.px:nth-child(30) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.55s;
}

.px:nth-child(31) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.px:nth-child(32) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.51s;
}

.px:nth-child(33) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(34) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.px:nth-child(35) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.px:nth-child(36) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.51s;
}

.px:nth-child(37) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.52s;
}

.px:nth-child(38) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.46s;
}

.px:nth-child(39) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.45s;
}

.px:nth-child(40) {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Click!</button>
<div class="line">
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
  <div class="px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я принимаю ответ  но если будет более четкый ответ приму его.И конечно спасибо вам что постарались плюс один от меня

Comment: @Spectr, постараюсь сделать более широким(в данный момент совсем мало времени)

Comment: я можно не находить время на создание такой чуды =(

Comment: @Spectr, в любом случае попробую воссоздать на HTML+CSS=)

Comment: если получится без js то ты БОГ =) без js подобное не сделать.Да твой вариант хорошо подходит но он не идеален

Comment: @Spectr, конечно не идеален, это вызов=)))

Comment: на самом деле, вариант @Arthur довольно точный для решения задачи, дело лишь в том что ручками придется прописывать все 40 transition-delay для каждой точки, Артур в своем ответе просто последовательно увеличивал задержку, в примере же она случайна. С помощью css препроцессоров можно решить генерацию данных задержек.

Comment: @Pavel, да, полностью согласен. Как раз добавил ссылку на Codepen, дабы упростить эту задачу

Comment: @Spectr, изменил ответ, можешь сравнить=)

Comment: @Arthur ОГО я незнал про такой фокус как ARRAY.from козырно :D твой ответ принят

Comment: @Pavel почему ты удалил свой ответ? =(

Answer (score 4):

Используется [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax). Идентичная анимация как на сайте из вопроса:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
paginationLineContent=$('.line-content');
if(paginationLineContent.find('.line-content .line-item').length <= 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 51; i++){
        paginationLineContent.append('<div class="line-item line-'+i+'"></div>');
    }
}
paginationLineItem = paginationLineContent.children();

function shuffle(array) {
    return array.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
}

function go(offset) {
  Line = new TimelineLite();
  Line.staggerTo(shuffle(paginationLineItem),1.3,{ x: offset, ease:Expo.easeInOut},.005,0);
}
            
go(25);

});
```

```css
.line-container .line-item {
    will-change: transform;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="line-container">
<div class="line-content">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ответ принят спасибо помощь

Comment: Хороший ответ, не задумывался об использовании TweenMax